# the elephant and elephant - proper and common noun?

Tags: nouns

1. "I saw **the elephant** at the zoo."
2. "I saw **elephants** at the zoo."

In sentence 1, is the word *the elephant* denote a proper noun and in sentence 2, is *elephants* denoting common noun?

Note: Please visit the link (Definite article section) -https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/540/01/

Comment: What explanation from that link makes you think it is, or is not, being used as the kinds of nouns you're asking about?

Comment: Hi John, I would like to clear my doubts about the type of NOUN these are. "the elephant" is proper noun and in 2nd sentence, "elephant" is a common noun. Please help me if I'm wrong.

Comment: You need to find what "proper" noun means searching the internet or looking up the dictionary. The word **elephant** can never be a proper noun unless it is a name of a person or place. Do you know what "proper noun" means?

Comment: I find myself wondering if Tapan is confusing definite article naming (talking about a specific instance of a thing) for proper nouns.

Comment: The article you link to says nothing about *proper* nouns.

Comment: In the first case a single specific elephant was seen.

Comment: @TapanBera ~ it would be a great help if you could explain which part of the link provided makes you think 'the elephant' is a proper noun, because I see nothing on that page to suggest it is. It would also help if you could tell us what you think a proper noun is, as that seems to be your problem here. In the meantime I will have to vote to close as the question doesn't make any sense as it stands.

Comment: This is a case of definite vs. indefinite, not about proper nouns.

Comment: @TapanBera Have a look at [this](http://www.chompchomp.com/terms/propernoun.htm) article about proper nouns. It might help clear things up for you. E.g. if there was a clown at the zoo with the stage name *The Elephant*, then *The Elephant* would be a proper noun. Sentence 1 should then have T and E in capitals, and would mean that you saw the clown named *The Elephant* at the zoo.

Answer (score 3):

**Proper** nouns are those which refer to people's and animals' names, organisation names, institutions like the Internet, months of the year, and many others. To sum up, the words whose writing is mandatory to be capitalised.

"The elephant" in your case is not a proper noun because I assume it's not the name of the elephant, it's just the species it belongs to. I believe in your sentences that "the elephant" was used to mean that there was only one elephant in the whole zoo, and "elephants" means that there was more than one.

But both are common nouns.